Index.js file does not exist in Cypress 13.7.3
I install Cypress 13.7.3 version and I am not able to find Index file in support folder. Does anyone know how and where to find Index.js file. I am using VS code.

The configuration for cypress/support/index.js is for legacy Cypress, pre version 10 so you would be upgrading an old project.
Currently, the "index" of the support folder is named e2e.js by default.
This is the contents normally given by Cypress to start with
cypress/suport/e2e.js
// ***********************************************************
// This example support/e2e.js is processed and
// loaded automatically before your test files.
//
// This is a great place to put global configuration and
// behavior that modifies Cypress.
//
// You can change the location of this file or turn off
// automatically serving support files with the
// 'supportFile' configuration option.
//
// You can read more here:
// https://on.cypress.io/configuration
// ***********************************************************

// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import './commands'

// Alternatively you can use CommonJS syntax:
// require('./commands')

You could create the file and paste that snippet in.

If you inherited the project, the support feature could have been turned off in the configuration settings.
cypress.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {

    // this setting disables the support feature - remove it to re-enable
    supportFile: false,

    // or add the explicit path
    supportFile: 'cypress/support/e2e.js',

    // or to keep using the legacy file
    supportFile: 'cypress/support/index.js',

  },
})


The cause could be one of two things:
No Support File Exists:
If you want Cypress to auto-generate some boilerplate files for you, you will have to run npx cypress open from the folder you want the cypress folder placed in.
Index.js Is Not The Default Support File in Cypress 10+
If you've opened Cypress and have the auto-generated files, and are still struggling to find support/index.js, the answer is most likely that Cypress changed their support file structure starting in Cypress 10. In versions below Cypress 10, the support file was located by default at support/index.js, and the auto-generated file would be located there. With Cypress 10 and above, Cypress auto-generated support files are located at support/e2e.js and support/component.js. Cypress now looks for one of several options in the support folder. These values can be overridden on the e2e- or component-level, if you'd prefer that Cypress still look for support/index.js.
